# Dynamically rename twig variable

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a  section in a HTML doc that is repeated over and over. It is almost always the same excepted the form input variable name I need to access.

```
<div>
  {{ form_widget(form.name1.parameter)}}
</div>
<div>
  {{ form_widget(form.name2.parameter)}}
</div>
<div>
  {{ form_widget(form.name3.parameter)}}
</div>
```

I would like to make a unique template for these three  and pass a parameter to this template so it changes the "nameX" parameter with proper value.

Meaning something like:

```
<div>
  {{ form_widget(form.{{goodname}}.parameter)}}
</div>
```

And in the calling twig template do something like:

```
{% include "divtemplate.html.twig" with {'goodname' : "name1"} %}
{% include "divtemplate.html.twig" with {'goodname' : "name2"} %}
{% include "divtemplate.html.twig" with {'goodname' : "name3"} %}
```

I'm able to use goodname alone in the document but not embeded in the form variable.

Do you know how to do this? I'm opened to workaround solutions.

Thanks a lot in advance

---

Edit: Correct way to do it (found thanks to Ahmed)

```
{% set subform = attribute(form, goodname) %} 
<div> 
     {{ form_widget(subform.parameter)}} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using the [attribute twig helper](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) which is commonly used to access a "dynamic" attribute of a variable.

Use `{{ attribute(form, goodname) }}` to access the form `name1`, `name2` or `name3` attributes. You can then call parameter on the returned object.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I hadn't understood this attribute helper in the twig doc due to laconic explainations. It doesn't work better since my problem is likely having nested evaluation operators that twig doesn't manage to handle. Meaning: {{ }} nested in a {% %}.

Comment: Edit: Actually it is working by doing:
{% set subform = attribute(form, goodname) %}
<div>
  {{ form_widget(subform.parameter)}}
</div>
I will accept your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like this (similar to what I ended up doing) since I had more than 3 subforms that followed the same pattern.

```
{% for idx in range(1, 3) %}
    <div>
        {{ form_widget(attribute(form, 'name' ~ idx ~ '.parameter')) }} 
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```